# Connect multiple grounds to one external connector in Eagle

Tags: power-supply, ground, eaglecad

For my project I designed 3 power supplies, a 5V and a 3.3V for the supply of the micro controller; and one 3.3V for 3 INA 226 shunt monitors.

I do have some questions regarding the ground.

The power supplies draw their power from an external adapter. I want to create 3 different polygon planes for the grounds, at this point they aren't connected to each other.

If I want to connect the 3 circuits to the external power supply, the 3 Grounds will be connected or am I wrong? is this going to be a problem or is there another solution?

At the INA226 shunt monitors, I want to measure the bus voltage from an USB. Now it measures the voltage using the bus voltage and the ground connected with the power supply. Now the USB bus voltage also has a ground, but I can't connect that to the IC, is this going to be a problem?? Maybe place a filter on the ground or something?

Comment: Please specify "external power supply". And at least supply us with a block diagram or a schematic. What primary voltages are your 3 supplies using?

Comment: you must connect the grounds together at some point, use a surface mount resistor package footprint or something in your eagle schematic but instead of putting a resistor, just use lots of solder or a 0-ohm resistor (not perfect, but whatever) to join the pads. you should connect all of these ground points at one place, and away from sensitive electronics (away from INA226 would be a good idea too)

Answer (score 1):

I love the "mulripple" grounds.  Mulripple must have a lot of ground loops, or ground bounce :^)

Re: Ground of the INA226 input.  I've never used the part, but it looks like it is to monitor a power supply that has the same ground as the [INA226.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf) So all your grounds need to be connected together at some point.